# How to solve "Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packagecloud.io/golang-migrate/migrate/ubuntu/ jammy:...."

Tags: 22.04

I installed golang-migrate in Ubuntu 22.04 and when I try to do

```
sudo apt update
```

After that, I get this error

```
E: Conflicting values set for option Signed-By regarding source https://packagecloud.io/golang-migrate/migrate/ubuntu/ jammy: /etc/apt/keyrings/golang-migrate_migrate-archive-keyring.gpg !=
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```